# Apple ID Sign in issue

Tags: apple-id, catalina

I recently updated to Catalina. Now, it seems that I cannot properly sign into my Apple ID on my MacBook Pro. My system preferences page looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Euu8M.jpg).

Has anyone else encountered this?

Addendum: It seems that I am actually logged in, I can see everything on the Apple ID page.

Comment: This happened to me, it seemed like a bug. I explored  other iCloud settings and used find my Mac then went back to my system preferences and it was fixed.

Answer (score 2):

This was solved by logging in and out, for anyone else asking.

Comment: Thanks for coming back and supplying the working solution to your question!